# How do I use max.num.names.before.forced.et.al?

Tags: bibtex

I am using the `IEEEtranSA` bibliography style which has `max.num.names.before.forced.et.al`. It seems to be a parameter which can be configured / customized. How can I set this to 5? Currently, I have author lists which have 10 entries.

Comment: Did you see the posting [Limiting the number of authors in the references with IEEEtran](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/164017/5001)?

Comment: @Mico I get `Undefined control sequence.
l.140 \bstctlcite` when I try it. Which package to I have to include?

Comment: @Mico Seems to work. I had to include `\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an MWE. Truncation is enabled if there are more than 5 authors; if truncation occurs, the first 5 authors are shown. Feel free to adjust either parameter to suit your needs.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@IEEEtranBSTCTL{BSTcontrol,
  CTLuse_forced_etal       = "yes",
  CTLmax_names_forced_etal = "5", 
  CTLnames_show_etal       = "5",
}
@misc{xyz,
  author = "AAA and BBB and CCC and DDD and EEE and FFF and GGG and HHH and III and JJJ",
  title  = "Thoughts",
  year   = 3001
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}     % or: just use the "IEEEtran" document class
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranSA} % alpha style, sorted alphabetically

\begin{document}
\bstctlcite{BSTcontrol}  % run this directive at start of document

\cite{xyz} % an ordinary citation command
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```